# Action after 3 checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 checkboxes as follows:

```
<div class="conditions" data-ng-controller="SignUpController as vm">
  <div class="conditions-content">
    Lorem Ipsum ...
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="condition1"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="condition2"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="condition3"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And an Angular 1 controller:

```
function SignUpController() {

  var vm = this;

  vm.start = function () {      

  }    

}
```

When all 3 checkboxes are selected I need to:
1. Hide the div with class `conditions`;
2. Call the function `start()` on the controller.

It needs to be with all conditions set to true.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Something like attributing a `ng-model` to the checkboxes and check their value? (Don't take it bad, but surprised that a user with that rep asks this kind of question..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) handler on all 3 inputs that will check for their values (that are set via [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)):

```
<div class="conditions" ng-class="{hidden: vm.hidden}" data-ng-controller="SignUpController as vm">
  <div class="conditions-content">
    Lorem Ipsum ...
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.cond1" ng-change="vm.check()" name="condition1"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.cond2" ng-change="vm.check()" name="condition2"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.cond3" ng-change="vm.check()" name="condition3"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And in controller:

```
function SignUpController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.hidden = false;

  vm.start = function () {

  };

  vm.check = function () {
    if (vm.cond1 && vm.cond2 && vm.cond3) {
      vm.hidden = true;
      vm.start();    
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use `ng-show`/`ng-hide`/`ng-if` to conditionally hide the container `<div>`.

Comment: yeah, depends on what you want to achieve, will add a note about them to the answer